# General Password Get/Set

Tags: password

I had sent my MacBook Pro for a hard-drive replacement which was returned back with a fresh installation of the OS.
But there is no password set when I need to "click to unlock".

1. How do I set my password ?
2. How do I retrieve my sudo password ?

Comment: Can you access everything on the computer or are there things locked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the account you are using doesn't need a password right now (otherwise how would you log in). Passwords can be changed in System Preferences -> Users and Groups

[image]

If you are an admin user, your sudo password is the same as your login password.